# Set Delegate in a mixed language project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, integration

I have an XCode6 mixed-language project, combining Swift and Objective C.

I created a Swift-based SingleView application, then added 2 Objective-C files, having contents as below:

Singleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SingletonDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)methodCalled;
@end

@interface Singleton : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SingletonDelegate> singletonDelegate;

+ (id)sharedSingleton;

- (void)method;

@end
```

Singleton.m

```
#import "Singleton.h"

static Singleton *shared = nil;

@implementation Singleton

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Interface

+ (Singleton *)sharedSingleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Singleton alloc] init];
    });

    return shared;
}

- (void)method {
    [self.singletonDelegate methodCalled];
}

@end
```

After setting up bridging header file as XCode suggested, I added `#import "Singleton.h"` into it.

In `ViewController.swift`, I tried to set `singletonDelegate` but always failed:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SingletonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Singleton.sharedSingleton().singletonDelegate = self // FAILED HERE!!!
        Singleton.sharedSingleton().method()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The error message is:

> Cannot assign to the result of this expression

Could any one show me how to fix this? (I am new in integrating Objective-C into Swift project)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class variable. Then set its delegate.

```
let singleton: Singleton = Singleton.sharedSingleton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       singleton.singletonDelegate = self
       //Singleton.sharedSingleton().singletonDelegate = self // FAILED HERE!!!
       //Singleton.sharedSingleton().method()
   }

fun methodCalled() {
   //This method gets called from the Singleton class through the delegate
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Valentin. It works! The reason my method did not work earlier is that `Singleton.sharedSingleton()` is `AnyObject!`, which does not contain `singletonDelegate`. You save my day!